# How to create an offset formula to use the reference in a cell (the cell the formula points to), not the cell address the formula is in?

Tags: excel

I thought this would be easy, but haven't figured it out on my own or found an existing answer online.

I have a worksheet set up to create charts from the contents of certain cells in a table.  I'd like to be able to point one cell to a value in another worksheet and have all the related cell populate with the values using the formula in the one cell as an address reference.

For example, if I put the formula ='Source Data'!G19 in cell E3, I would like cell E4 below it to act like it has the formula ='Source Data'!G20 (one row below in the Source Data worksheet) and populate that value while cell F3 to the right would act like it had the formula ='Source Data'!H20 in it.  So the new worksheet would just mirror the table of data from the Source Data worksheet for as many columns or rows as I need.

I'd tried to figure this out with offset, indirect, match and address functions, but have failed.

It is important to note that the formula needs to be able to identify the actual cell address, not just match the value from the formula because the same values show up multiple times in the Source Data worksheet.

Any help or direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This shift occurs automatically when you copy the cell `E3` and paste into the other cells. In short you want this autofill mechanism to trigger automatically when you change the formula in `E3`? I dont see a way to achieve this without VBA (or other Excel automation language).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Now that I made the post, I was wondering if it is possible to the use the =formulatext function or other one to pull out just the column and row references from the formula (i.e. just pull out the "G" and the "19" from the formula ='Source Data'!G19 and then I could have it increment one more column or one more row.  I just tried using =formulatext and the =right() function, but it isn't cooperating for reasons I can't figure out.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my approach:
I have a workbook with 2 spreadsheets `Source Data` and `Results`, on `Source Data`, I have the "Static" table that contains all my values from `A1` to `D12`(This can be any number of cells, as long as you use an equal range in the `Results` sheet).

On `Results`, Cell `A1` is reserved for the "guide" cell from `Source Data`, written in the following format: `''Source Data'!A1` (note the two single quotes at the begging). I chose to start at Cell `B2` on the `Results` sheet, you can switch the formula however you like.

The desired result is achieved by using the following formula on `B2`:

`=IF(CELL("contents",OFFSET(INDIRECT($A$1),ROW(B2)-2,COLUMN(B2)-2))<>0,CELL("contents",OFFSET(INDIRECT($A$1),ROW(B2)-2,COLUMN(B2)-2)),"")`

then drag down and to the right the same number of maximum cells that exist on `Source Data` and the result will adjust accordingly.

I prepared a Google Sheets [document](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RvZYtepMNOeg80LJn8w0YHN9_VcHlk5rH9Ylts5LSxY/edit#gid=337404621) with all of the information.

Comment: This is wonderful...very clear explanation and it took just a little modification to work in my own worksheet.  One question...is it possible to modify the formulas so I'm able to sort the RESULTS worksheet afterwards?  I'd like to maintain the link to the SOURCE DATA (if I need to update it), but create sorted graphs in the RESULTS worksheet.  I'm guessing this might involve making the B2 into absolute reference ($B$2) once it has been copied across the cells I need it to function in.  Is that right?  Or is there another way?  Thanks in advance.